# Which folder(s) should I save to keep my coonfiguration and installed programs when I make a backup?

Tags: backup

I want to back up my entire configuration of Ubuntu right now.

The problem (if it is...) is that I don't know whether all the repoitories, shells (I use Zsh), GNOME themes, and things I've installed through `apt-get`, and lots more stuff... will be backed up if I only choose to back up the home folder.

How can I make a backup that saves all that?

Comment: Deja Dup is not good for a system backup if you are asking about it. It's good for your personal files.

Comment: `/home` + `/etc` should be enough but it depends on your personal needs.

Comment: /etc is not enough